# Tomcat 7: Include virtual host definitions from a directory?

Tags: tomcat

I'm setting up a new Tomcat 7.0.33 server, and I'm looking for a simple way to include a directory full of virtual host definition XML files for configuration.

I've found that it's possible to do XML includes from server.xml, but this requires a line in server.xml for each file, and is no less work than just having the entire config right in server.xml. I'm looking for something similar to Apache's Include directive.

The end result I'm looking for is to have a directory I can drop an XML file into that Tomcat will pick up on the next restart, without having to modify server.xml. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No mecanism exists to load an entire directory of files in tomcat config. As it is XML based, you need to describe all included resources.